# Redux fetch returning empty payload array

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm trying to fetch data from API (Now, I just have an array for testing) and show it in my screen.

I create an action file:

```
import {
  GET_TENANT_DATA
} from './Types';

export const getTenants = ({ userID }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const test = ['Saab', 'Volvo', 'BMW']; // Later it will be changed for axios fetch
    dispatch({
      type: GET_TENANT_DATA,
      payload: test
    });
  };
};
```

My reducer:

```
import {
  GET_TENANT_DATA
} from '../actions/Types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  error: false,
  data: []
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TENANT_DATA:
      return { ...state, error: false, tenants: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Then, in my screen I test it by console.log:

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userID')
      .then((value) => {
        const userId = JSON.parse(value);
        this.props.getTenants(userId);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.data);
...
```

However, the log display an empty array instead of the ['Saab', 'Volvo', 'BMW']. Does anyone know why it is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `data` property in your reducer you are setting `tenants` property and `data` is left as it was set initially - empty.

Change your reducer like this:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TENANT_DATA:
      return { ...state, error: false, data: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```